# How to dump full device settings on recent Samsung from Linux?

Tags: rooting, linux, 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-3

In my case, I would really be annoyed to no longer have phone/lte working because of the detection of a non Samsung firmware.

So I’d like to root the device (or boot from the sd card) by modifying the current firmware (especially since an official Samsung update changed the bootloader along with the kernel last month).

I want to dump full storage including the apps stored on `/data`. But so far, all I found doesn’t work on the latest Samsung or is for Windows only.

Comment: Maybe firmware download mode?

Comment: @alecxs actual root methods de factor involve downgrading the firmware without the bootloader or installing an open source firmware that wouldn’t be able to use the ꜱɪᴍ card. So they would brick the device. In order to root, I need to backup and dump the current firmware in order to modify it.

Comment: is this for your device? https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3769742

Comment: @alecxs correct but without support for the latest update. And might also result in erase of `/data`. I’ve got a lot of apps that can no longer be downloaded from the play store.

Comment: @alecxs in fact I don’t even want to root it but access the `/data` partition in a way that requires one time root access. And maybe even keep Safety Net with ᴅʀᴍ based app happy.

Comment: you can try to get apk files from adb backup -apk

Comment: @alecxs which doesn’t work in my case (the process crash on the device). Maybe an ᴏᴛᴀ would be able to do it ? By access, I mean to write.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=72204306&postcount=978